# Aren't the statements below contradictory in [stmt.ambig]/3?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[[stmt.ambig]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#3):

> **The disambiguation is purely syntactic**; that is, the meaning of the names occurring in such a statement, beyond whether they are
>   type-names or not, is not generally used in or changed by the
>   disambiguation. Class templates are instantiated as necessary to
>   determine if a qualified name is a type-name. **Disambiguation
>   precedes parsing**, and a statement disambiguated as a declaration may
>   be an ill-formed declaration. If, during parsing, a name in a template
>   parameter is bound differently than it would be bound during a trial
>   parse, the program is ill-formed. No diagnostic is required. [ Note:
>   This can occur only when the name is declared earlier in the
>   declaration. —end note ]

Given that syntax analysis is a synonym for parsing, how come disambiguation can precede parsing?

Comment: I don't see the term "syntax analysis"  in that quote from the standard.

Comment: @NeilButterworth "syntax analysis" and "parsing" are considered synonyms in the literature. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

Comment: If you are asking  language-lawyer questions about C++, you need to use the language of the C++ Standard, not that of Wikipedia.

Comment: Another good question is why it says "template parameter". The context and example suggest it means "function parameter", but it's been that way since at least C++03.

Comment: @NeilButterworth Don't be so pedantic. The standard uses the word "parsing" 18 times without defining it.

Comment: @WaldB  How often does it use the term "syntax analysis"?

Comment: @aschepler I think it indeed means "template parameter", like `sizeof(a)` in [this example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SUEjtNvhDAJ9EWh1).

Comment: @WaldB Yes, but most uses of "pars*" are clearly talking about either deciding what preprocessor tokens are formed from source characters or deciding what grammar symbols are formed from tokens. And it seems like that can't be the meaning here, since now disambiguation is the thing deciding whether some tokens form a _declaration-statement_ or an _expression-statement_.

Comment: @cpplearner Maybe. Except in that example `sizeof(a)` is in a template argument, not a template parameter. But if it should say "template argument", it's maybe saying when a name just in a function parameter turns out to actually be a previous declarator in the same declaration, that might or might not be well-formed depending on the new meaning, but within a template argument this is always ill-formed NDR? Is that your interpretation?

Comment: @NeilButterworth It uses the term "syntactic analysis" in [\[stmt.ambig\]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.ambig#2)